# Update filed without refreshing

Tags: ajax

I'm a beginner with Ajax and I'm trying to update a field from database by clicking a button. This is my code but is not working, so what I'm doing wrong?

Controller:

```
 public function make_vizib($id) {
 $this->load->model('retrive');
 $this->retrive->up_vizib($id);
 $this->load->view('make_vizib');}
```

Model :

```
function up_vizib($id)
{              
$this->db->set('vizibil', '0');
$this->db->where('Id_utilizat', $id);
$this->db->update('places');        
}
```

```
$(function() {

    $("#submit-choice-b1").click(function(e) {
       var result = confirm("are you sure ?");
            if (result==true) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "make_vizib",
                    data: { id: 4; }

                    success: function(xhr){
                        alert('updated');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: _"but is not working"_ - what is the error? Have you checked your browser console?

Comment: Nothing happens, I have checked my database and it doesn't update it. There's no error in my console